# Access alpha value of opengl texture pixels

Tags: opengl, c++, collision-detection

I'm trying to get the alpha values of each pixel of an image that I'm loading onto a texture so i can use it to check for per pixel collision. 
I have a texture class:

```
struct GLTexture {
    std::string filePath = "";
    GLuint id;
    int width;
    int height;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> alphaPixels;
};
```

When i bind the texture i want to do something like this:

```
//Generate the openGL texture object
glGenTextures(1, &(texture.id));

//Bind the texture object
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
//Upload the pixels to the texture
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(out[0]));

for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j<height; j++)
    {
        alphaPixels[i][j] = getAlpha(GL_TEXTURE_2D); ///<something like this line but i don't know how to access to alpha value
    }
}
```

How can i get the alpha value of each pixel of the image? Is this even a feasible thing to do or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have uploaded the image, you probably still have it in main memory. To access any given pixel, you can get its address by doing the following:

```
uint8* pixelAddress = (uint8*)out + bytesPerRow * row + bytesPerPixel * col;
```

Here I'm assuming that `bytesPerRow` is the number of bytes in a row of pixels in the texture. Furthermore, I'm assuming that `bytesPerPixel` is the number bytes in a pixel. As you can probably guess, `row` and `col` are the row and column for the pixel you wish to access. Note that this will give the address of the first byte of the pixel. If it's an RGBA pixel, you'll need to add 3 to it to get the address of the alpha channel.

The point being that you don't need to create a new alpha-only image, as you already have the alpha information in main memory.